# How do I get the last id from a table after multiple insert

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am adding data to three tables, I needed to get the last ID of the first table to use in the second table, which was successful with `$this->db->insert_id()` function, Trying that with the second table still gives me the ID of the first table. The arrangement of my code is:

```
    function addcrm() {

    //Post data collection array from the webform form
    $customerdata = array(

                    "salutation"=>$this->input->post('salutation'),  
                    "mobilenumber"=>$this->input->post('mobilenumber'), 
                    "emailaddress"=>$this->input->post('emailaddress') 

    );
    $this->db->insert('api_customer', $customerdata);

    $customer=$this->db->insert_id();
    $leaddata = array(
                    "fieldrep"=>$this->input->post('fieldrep'), 
                    "fk_customerID"=>$customer, 

                    "te"=>$this->input->post('takage'),
                    "othercost"=>$this->input->post('othercost')                    

    );

    $this->db->insert('api_lead', $leaddata);



  $leadID = $this->db->insert_id();

 for ($i =0; $i<count($_POST['w_product']); $i++){
     $productdata = array(
         "name" => $_POST['w_product'][$i],
         "type" => $_POST['w_type'][$i],
          "cost" => $_POST['w_cost'][$i],
         "fk_leadID"=> $leadID
          );
           $this->db->insert('api_prod',$productdata);

 }  
    $url = base_url('cXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
    redirect($url);

    }
```

Comment: lack of `()` solves your problem? `$leadID = $this->db->insert_id;` -> `$leadID = $this->db->insert_id();`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something obviously in the second call. ;)

```
$customer = $this->db->insert_id();

$leadIdD  = $this->db->insert_id;
```

See? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try working with the following methods:

```
$this->db->start_cache(); // Before query
$this->db->stop_cache(); // After query
$this->db->flush_cache(); // Clear query
```

This way you make clear and flushed queries.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using an auto increment table you may try using MYSQL_LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Comment: That would most likely be what `$this->db->insert_id` already does. Also, it would suddenly hard code the site to `mysql` only.

Comment: I am suggesting that you would try the native approach and so if it doesn't work you may disregard this answer